# Karate API - Could not pass the variable value in the path

Tags: api, karate

I am trying to pass the variable value of AppraisalID but it is not recognized. Please help

```
Given path '/products/propertyedge/appraisal'
    And request '{"valuationId":"372629"}'
    When method Post
    Then status 201
    * def location = responseHeaders['Location'][0]
    * def appraisalId = location.substring(location.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    * print appraisalId
    Given path 'products/propertyedge/appraisal/{appraisalId}'
    And param action = 'view'
    When method Get
    Then status 200
    And assert response.appraisalId == <appraisalId>
```

Response:
[image: response]

#karate #api

Tried with scenario outline variable <> but in vain. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#path

```
Given path 'products/propertyedge/appraisal', appraisalId
```